# Search in Salesforce Files Preview

Tags: files, servicecloud, sales-cloud, preview

When opening a document (pdf, doc, ppt, xlsx, etcetera) that has been uploaded to Files in Salesforce; it is not possible to search within the document. When pressing CTRL+F in the overlay preview, you get the default web browser search. Which doesn't search in the overlay.

We need to be able to search within document without downloading it. As you can do with for example Gmail.

Is there a way to solve this? Could be some app on AppExchange or perhaps a web browser extension. Also open to custom solutions.